# How to mitigate errors caused by referencing client side technologies on server side rendering

Tags: server-side-rendering

How to mitigate errors caused by referencing client side technologies on server side rendering, like `document`, `document.cookie`, `localStorage` etc?

For example, I use React.js and server side rendering. I render the client side gui components on server, also send the same components to the client side separately. Server side and client side component rendered output and the props (React props) supplied to it should be same to not to loose the benefit of the server side rendering. On the client side React.js looks and decides which one to render on this two conditions; rendered output and the props supplied to React component. On these components I can maybe have client side tech references on the client side version, but I get errors when I reference them on the server side versions.

Since the javascript codes to this two versions of gui components may be different, I know I can have them different, server side version does not reference `document.cookie` for example. But for the simplicity of the development, and avoiding errors due to this, this is not very straightforward, IMHO. Also will browser run the client side version of the component in such cases to reach the `document.cookie` or `localStorage`, if not this mitigation does not work at all.